# React with Redux and Router - server rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to make server rendering work with async calls. My problem is, data isn't being downloaded before the render.

My code (also available on github: https://github.com/tomekbuszewski/server-rendering)

server.js

```
require('babel-register');

import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { getState } from 'redux';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'

import routes from './app/routes';
import store from './app/store';

const app = express();
const port         = 666;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (renderProps) {
      console.log(renderProps.components);
      res.send(renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
        </Provider>
      ))
    } else {
      console.log('err')
    }
  });
});

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/data', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'data')));

app.listen(port);
console.log(`localhost:${port}`);
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './Components/App';

const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

App component has a fetch function:

```
const fetch = (dispatch) => {
    const endpoint = '/data/index.json';

    axios.get(endpoint).then((res) => {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(res.data, d => {
            const payload = {
                id:    d.id,
                title: d.title
            };

            dispatch({type: 'ADD_CONTENT', payload});
        });
    });
};
```

which dispatches 'ADD_CONTENT' action:

```
case 'ADD_CONTENT':
  return { ...state, data: [...state.data, action.payload] };
```

All works great client-side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your redux actions should return a promise that fulfill when the store is correctly loaded with the data

for example:

```
const fetch = (dispatch) => {
    const endpoint = '/data/index.json';

    return axios.get(endpoint).then((res) => {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(res.data, d => {
            const payload = {
                id:    d.id,
                title: d.title
            };

            dispatch({type: 'ADD_CONTENT', payload});
        });
    });
};
```

2. You have to use a wrapper like [redux-connect](https://github.com/makeomatic/redux-connect) that calls those actions before loading the component.

In your example, the routed component is `App`

In that case, you would decorate that component with the needed redux action that will preload the data.

```
import { asyncConnect } from 'redux-connect';

@asyncConnect([{
    promise: ({ store: { dispatch } }) => {
        // `fetch` is your redux action returning a promise
        return dispatch(fetch());
    }
}])
@connect(
    state => ({
        // At this point, you can access your redux data as the
        // fetch will have finished 
        data: state.myReducer.data
    })
)
export default class App extends Component {
    // ...the `data` prop here is preloaded even on the server
}
```

*The `@connect` can decorate a nested component, if you dont use the data in the top container, as the store is available app-wide, but the `@asyncConnect` must decorate components directly called by `react-router`, it cannot be used (so far) on nested components in the rendered tree, or they won't be parsed during initial render*

Because the rendering of the components tree occurs only once on the server, that function cannot be called by the component itself, it needs to be called *before* it loads, *via* `redux-connect` and a redux action supporting promises, for example using `redux-thunk` middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `redux-connect`, but I have to admit that their example is very confusing. I got the server path, but the component one is very strange to me. How should I connect my data with `@asyncConnect`, should I ditch my reducers and use only `reduxAsyncConnect `?

Comment: In your main `combineReducers(...)` call, you just have to include the reducer from `redux-connect`, without any other impact on your other reducers. I don't know if it's even mandatory, maybe to track the preloading status, I personally use it in my layout to display a "loading" message when the loading happens on the client, *ie* all subsequent route changes after the first SSR.

Comment: But I agree it's not easy to use, needs a bit of trying :-) I did not find *easier* though. (a few month ago)

Comment: Okay, so the first question returns - how should I use `asyncConnect` with my current code?

Comment: I updated my answer with the actual component declaration with `reduxAsyncConnect`

Comment: Thanks, great example, but I can't seem to find `@connect`, is it from `redux-connect`? Also, can this be done without decorators?

Comment: `@connect` from `react-redux` is how I use react with redux, not sure if there is another way? Like explained in that tutorial: http://www.jchapron.com/2015/08/14/getting-started-with-redux/#3buildingtheui. You can use it as a function on the component that you export, instead of a decorator. (See the react-redux docs, they use it that way)

Comment: I totally forgot that `connect` comes from react-redux ;-) I am using it already: https://github.com/tomekbuszewski/server-rendering/blob/connect/app/Components/App/index.js
Also, when I try to run the server and enter it, I can't. It simply "loads" and then says that my host is unreachable.

Comment: If i read your component code correctly, I would rather call `dispatch(actions.fetch());` instead of `dispatch(fetch())` in `asyncConnect` (and get rid of `mapDispatchToProps` and `componentDidMount`)

Comment: Actually I did this before writing the last comment, didn't help. Still getting `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` from Chrome. Problem lies somewhere within `loadOnServer` in server.js, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry for another comment (and MANY thanks for sticking with me here!), I just found out that the problem is that `loadOnServer` returns an error `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`. I thought that `redux-connect` handles this problem.

Comment: Do you use redux-thunk ? It handles promises-as-actions. Otherwise, yes, out of the box you cannot dispatch non-objects.

Comment: No, I don't. Actually, I am trying to get this done with as little addons as possible. Please refer to my github link (branch `connect`).

Comment: I added thunk (not sure if I used it correctly though), nothing changed.